# MediaWiki Share CSS among instances

Tags: css, mediawiki

I am running a server that hosts several disjunct instances of MediaWiki for several customers. There are a few set of CSS adjustments, which I would like to apply server-wide and "group-wide".

I already checked out WikiPedia's stacks of [CSS classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Catalogue_of_CSS_classes), but they are all predefined and would most probably be overwritten on updates.

It would be perfect, if there were some kind of css.d folder, where I could store links to CSS files, but to the best of my knowledge there is not such a thing.

How should I realize sharing a CSS file among several instances?

Comment: hmm.. why not just create a CSS file and include it as a link in all other instances? it will be in one location and loaded in all

Comment: That is the basic concept, which I do have in mind: I create a CSS file and make links to that file in all instances. The question is: how do I make MediaWiki aware of that linked file? Where is the best point to "jump in"? I don't want to touch any of the distributed files ...

Comment: This could help: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ExpandCss with it you can add custom CSS and you can probably use an @import call to your global CSS file URL

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier then to put an @import call into MediaWiki:Common.css? Just wondering ... either ways I would have to edit the data in the database. I am still hoping for some robust versatile file based solution. To give an example: I have already successfully extracted shared modules into a shared module file, which I incorporate into the virtual server setups in LocalSettings.php - something like that, ie a few lines of code in LocalSettings.php would be nice - I just don't know the right hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a [wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family), install the [GlobalCssJs extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GlobalCssJs) and edit the MediaWiki:Global.js/MediaWiki:Global.css pages on the central wiki ([manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:GlobalCssJs)), as you would do to [customise a wiki's CSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Stylesheets).

Alternatively, write your own extension to make all your custom changes in a single place (the code repository) and then deploy them to all wikis with the usual methods you use to update code.